# How to add rows with the average values of selected rows into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:
The data is made of 3 copies as in the first column. Each of these copies contain the same elements, i.e they have 2 sequences each, which are in turn made up of 3 different types: A, R2 and R3.

```
Copy    sequence    type    ntv
1        1           A      0.45
1        1           R2     0.878
1        1           R3     1.234
1        2           A      -7.890
1        2           R2     2.345
1        2           R3     -0.871
2        1           A      -0.098
2        1           R2     -0.007
2        1           R3     9.089
2        2           A      1.567
2        2           R2     -0.764
2        2           R3     17.908
3        1           A      4.980
3        1           R2     2.34
3        1           R3     1.280
3        2           A      -9.189
3        2           R2     -7.09
3        2           R3     -0.009
```

I would like to create a data frame that looks like the one below, such that for each sequence in the same copy, the average of R2 and R3 is given on a new line as type 'R'. What I mean is that in copy 1 for example, how can I find the mean value of R2 and R3 for each of the sequences.

```
Copy    sequence    type    ntv
1        1           A      0.45
1        1           R2     0.878
1        1           R3     1.234
1        1           R      1.056
1        2           A      -7.890
1        2           R2     2.345
1        2           R3     -0.871
1        2           R      0.737
2        1           A      -0.098
2        1           R2     -0.007
2        1           R3     9.089
2        1           R      4.541
2        2           A      1.567
2        2           R2     -0.764
2        2           R3     17.908
2        2           R      8.572
3        1           A      4.980
3        1           R2     2.34
3        1           R3     1.280
3        1           R      1.81
3        2           A      -9.189
3        2           R2     -7.09
3        2           R3     -0.009
3        2           R      -3.549
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
avg_type = [(('R2','R3'),'R')]
for i in set(df['Copy']):
    cp = df[df['Copy'] == i]
    for i in set(df['sequence']):
        seq = df[df['sequence'] == i]        
    for oldname, newname in avg_type:
        avg = seq.loc[seq['type'].isin(oldname)]
        if len(avg) > 1:
            newrow = avg.loc[avg.index[0]]
            newrow['ntv'] = avg['ntv'].mean()
            newrow['type'] = newname
            df.loc[-1] = newrow     
            df.index += 1
```

I have only managed to somehow figure out how to find the average of R2 and R3 per sequence (in other words I get 2 values instead of 6), but even the new rows are not properly placed as I want.

How can I extend my selection criteria to consider the 'Copy' number as well? I would appreciate any help or directions on how to go about it using pandas or python in general. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [68]: df.append(
    ...:     df[df['type'].isin(['R2','R3'])]
    ...:       .groupby(['Copy','sequence'], as_index=False)
    ...:       ['ntv'].mean()
    ...:       .assign(type='R')) \
    ...:   .sort_values(['Copy','sequence'])[df.columns]
    ...:
Out[68]:
    Copy  sequence type      ntv
0      1         1    A   0.4500
1      1         1   R2   0.8780
2      1         1   R3   1.2340
0      1         1    R   1.0560
3      1         2    A  -7.8900
4      1         2   R2   2.3450
5      1         2   R3  -0.8710
1      1         2    R   0.7370
6      2         1    A  -0.0980
7      2         1   R2  -0.0070
..   ...       ...  ...      ...
11     2         2   R3  17.9080
3      2         2    R   8.5720
12     3         1    A   4.9800
13     3         1   R2   2.3400
14     3         1   R3   1.2800
4      3         1    R   1.8100
15     3         2    A  -9.1890
16     3         2   R2  -7.0900
17     3         2   R3  -0.0090
5      3         2    R  -3.5495

[24 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer! May I ask one more question? Please how can I do a 'Copy' ranking of the average R values. What I mean is that for each of the sequences, how can I rank the R values based on the 'Copy' column so that for example I know which copy has the lowest R for sequence 1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Cave, please open a new question and post there your sample input data set and your desired data set (like in this question) - otherwise it's difficult to understand what are you after. Please don't change this question as it will invalidate already given answers...

Answer (score 1):

This will also generate type "R". You could append and sort, and assign type "R" like MaxU's function.

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,"type"] != "A" ].groupby( ("Copy","sequence") , as_index = False).mean()
```